# Blockchain Wallet API

Tags: transactions, bitcoin

I’m aware that transactions via the wallet API will incur a 0.0005 BTC miners fee (https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api). In the same notes, Blockchain states the “Send Many transactions” procedure can group a number of recipients in the same transaction. I’m seeking confirmation that the same  0.0005 BTC miners fee applies to the single transaction of multiple recipients (that is, it is not a ‘per recipient’ transaction fee, but is in fact an ‘event’ fee - the event being one transaction on the block chain with multiple recipients)?

Comment: maybe better asked on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Each transaction requires a fee to be accepted by miners.

It will be separate fees on a per transaction basis.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a way to disable the miners fee. If you login and click account settings (screenshot: http://screencloud.net/v/gqL3) and then click the general tab (screenshot: http://screencloud.net/v/jrwI), you should be able to change the fee to frugal (screenshot: http://screencloud.net/v/pCU1) which will not make you pay the fee until it is absolutely necessary! Hope this helped!